# hide MarkerCluster when is 0 in React js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image]

I am using the google maps api in my React project

How can I hide the markers cluster when there is not markers inside ? I've tried with clearMarkers() but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look on this question, it is similar to yours. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090624/hide-markerclusterer-in-google-map)

you can try setting it to null

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```